# Sudo for OpenLDAP

Tags: sudo, ldap, openldap

I needed to install `sudo-ldap` support for LDAP enabled server.

**The question:**

On which machine (ldap-client or ldap-server) I have to build & install the package I dowloaded from www.sudo.ws ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use the `sudo` package built with LDAP support so that you can have the sudoers database distributed via LDAP, then you have to install this package on every server you want to use sudo!
Note: each server shall have `libldap` installed.

It is no required on your LDAP server per se.
But you can also install on it if you want to use this version of `sudo`.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarification.  Maybe you know some comprehensive guide on installing `ldap-client-sudo` packages?

Comment: what's `ldap-client-sudo` package? I can't find it the debian repository. Maybe you meant `sudo-ldap`? If yes, you can look at https://www.leonis.at/blog/ldap-integration-sudo-users

Comment: I am running centOS 7.3. CentOS repo has no package called `ldap-client-sudo` I made this name up for better clarity in reading.  Thanks this guide you sent me looks promising I will give it a shot.  Also centOS has no repository for similar packages also.